# select in simmer library does not consider the resource available?

Tags: r, simulation

According to the documentation of simmer [here](http://r-simmer.org/reference/select.html).

---

I am returning the vector of resources available according to a variable.If value of `attr["resource"]<2` the available resource should be only `berth1` and `attr["resource"]>=2` the available sources should be `c("berth2","berth3")`.But whenever `attr["resource"]>=2` even though `berth2` is not available it is assigning the `berth2`.
But what I want is it has to select the resource according to the policy `First available` ,So it has to select `berth3` whenever `berth2` is not available

```
select(resources = function(attrs) ifelse(attrs["resource"]<2, "berth1",c("berth2","berth3")),policy="first-available") %>%
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be stated more clearly in the documentation: if `resources` is a character vector, the `policy` applies; if `resources` is a function, it must return a single resource which will be selected, i.e., the `policy` is ignored.

Comment: thanks.But when `attr["resource"] > 2` I am returning a character vector so the policy should be applied right?

Comment: That is what I am saying: in the current state, no, it is not. Defining `resources` as a function automatically invalidates the policy. But now that you mention it, your use case sounds reasonable to me (i.e., apply the policy when a character vector is supplied, even if it is returned from a function), and this could be a nice addition for the next release. Could you please open an issue in Github?

Comment: 's Ok Thanks.got it.

Comment: FYI, [the next release will support your use case](https://github.com/r-simmer/simmer/issues/92).